# newbie hadoop .. distributed cache

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a mapper

```
public class BuildGraph{
   public void config(JobConf job){ <==this block doesnt seems to be exexcuting at all :(
    super.configure(job);
    this.currentId = job.getInt("currentId",0);
    if (this.currentId!=0){ 
    // I call a method from differnt class to build a distributed cache
    }
   }
  public void map(....){
....  
}
```

}

now the main code where this is called..

```
public void run( String params,curId){
 JobConf conf = new JobConf(classname.class);
 conf.setInt("currentId",299); <--note this i am setting the value here
 conf.setMapperClass(BuildGraph.class);
 //.... 
  JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
```

But the problem is config method in the code is not executing as though "currentId" returns 299 in main loop but it is not set at all in the mapper class.
what am i doing wrong

Link to full code
http://pastebin.com/DRPXUm62

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using the right contract since you are not extending `MapReduceBase` and not implementing `Mapper`. Also the method should be called `configure` and not `config`. Try something like this:

```
public class BuildGraph extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<K, V, K, V> {
    public void configure(JobConf job) {
        // this will get called once at the beginning of the task
    }

    public void map(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fraz Can you post your full mapper code and main? If too big you can make a link to external text editor

Comment: Just incase you are wondering, I am expecting line no 17 to be executed as in line number 93 I am setting a non zero value

Comment: What does line 14 print you? Does it get executed at all?

Comment: NOpe :( It never executed that block